# Error installing Scran package using Anaconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda, anaconda3

So I try to install the Scran, use  `conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-scran` then got the error like this:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done `Solving
> environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
> solve. Solving environment: failed with repodata from
> current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
>
> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with
> flexible solve. Solving environment: \  Found conflicts! Looking for
> incompatible packages. This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to
> abort.
> failed
>
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be
> incompatible with each other:
>
> Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
>
> Package zlib conflicts for: bioconductor-scran ->
> r-base[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
> python=3.8 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
>
> Package ncurses conflicts for: python=3.8 ->
> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0'] python=3.8 ->
> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0'] ->
> ncurses[version='6.0.*|>=6.0,<7.0a0']
>
> Package libgcc-ng conflicts for: python=3.8 ->
> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a'] ->
> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0|>=9.3.0'] python=3.8 ->
> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0|>=7.5.0']
>
> Package libstdcxx-ng conflicts for: python=3.8 ->
> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
> python=3.8 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']The following
> specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:
>
> - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
> - bioconductor-scran -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
> - python=3.8 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
>
> Your installed version is: 2.31`

I have tried many ways, but didn't work. I still don't know how to fix. Could someone give me a favor?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid mixing Python and R in the same environment. Also, Bioconda assumes the following channel priority:

```
conda-forge > bioconda > defaults
```

Try creating a dedicated environment for your Bioconductor work, and make sure to pin an `r-base`:

**bioc_r41.yaml**

```yaml
name: bioc_r41
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - r-base=4.1
  - bioconductor-scran
```

Create the environment with:

```bash
conda env create -n bioc_r41 -f bioc_r41.yaml
```

Alternatively, one can achieve this with an *ad hoc* command, but it is rather verbose:

```bash
conda create -n bioc_r41 -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults r-base=4.1 bioconductor-scran
```